# Drupal nested / complex / sub content types

Tags: drupal, types, nested

I am trying to create multi-user system for CV managing using Drupal.

The basic idea is:

- Each User has his own CV.
- Each CV has several predefined sections as Education, Work experience, etc.
- Each Section consists of unlimited {Dates range - Text} entries.

I've created two new content types - CV and Date_Range_Text but I cannot link them together, e.g. to make Date_Range_Text a complex/nested content type, used in the CV's sections entries.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [Field Collection module](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

1. Create a content type called CV.
2. Add a field_collection field to CV called education and allow unlimited entries.
3. Edit the education field_collection item and add a date field and a text field.
4. Do the same for work experience and any other fields.

Now when someone creates a new CV they can add unlimited education items, each consisting of a date and some text.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But is it possible to provide users with ability to reorder their records?

Comment: Yes, there are drag handles on each field collection item allowing you to re-order all of the items.