# Drupal Profile2 / Field collection sorting records

Tags: drupal, collections, field, profile

As continuation of this article [Drupal nested / complex / sub content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174966/drupal-nested-complex-sub-content-types) I have a new question.

As described, using Profile2 and Field collection I've managed to create multi-user CV management system:

1. Created a content type called CV.
2. Added a field_collection field to CV called education and allow unlimited entries.
3. Edited the education field_collection item and add a date field and a text field.
4. Did the same for work experience and any other fields.

Unfortunately, users should be able to reorder the records (date-text), e.g. to put some of the entries before others. For the moment being they appear in the order of their input.

How to achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image below shows a field collection I have made with 3 fields.
One the left of each collection item is a drag handle. 
You can re-order content using these handles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. If I create a CV as a Content type + Field collections, then records could be reordered with the drag handles. The problem here is that users should have exactly one or eventually two CVs. Using Content types they could be unlimited.

Comment: And when using Profile2 + Field collection, there re no handles - just simple CRUD operations.

Comment: I'm not sure why your not seeing drag handles. You will need to debug the issue. You can stop more then 2 CVs being created using hook_form_alter and adding a new validation function.

Comment: It worked! Profile2 + Field collections. The handles were not there because Home » Administration » Structure » Profile types » CV > Widget  was set to hidden. I've changed it to Embedded and everything ran as charm :-) Thank you

Comment: Arr - hidden widget - glad you got it all sorted :)